# Python package for pharsing most common scientific data formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, scientific-computing

There are a number of ways of storing huge scientific data. VTK (text and binary), HDF4, SDF, ASDF, etc. are widely used formats for this purpose, for example. NumPy's binary data format or simple txt files are also an option.

These all have their respective Python libraries. But if one wants to write a flexible program that supports saving and loading to/from these formats, using 10+ different libraries just for this purpose has it's drawbacks.

**Is there a Python package that can manage simple reading/writing to most common scientific data formats?**

Comment: The reason I ask this question is because I came along such a package a while ago, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: I know `pandas` works with HDF. After googling it seems it also works with SDF. So i would suggest trying `pandas`.

Comment: It's definetly not Pandas, bu tI'll take a look definetly. The module I found was specifically designed for conversions between data formats, but also supports loading and saving from NumPy arrays/etc.